# How to count frequency of specific words ifrom my csv file in R?

Tags: r, tm

There are only reviews in my csv document (Only rows no columns).I want to count the frequency of word for example love, like , best from my csv file. I dont want frequency of each and every word . I only want how many time these three word appear in my csv document .
 I had tries these code but it is giving me a frequency of each and every word which i dont want. 
Can anyone help me out how to count freq of specific words or list of specific words?

```
texts <- read.csv("./Data/fast food/Domino's/Domino's veg pizza.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts))
    toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\|")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("blabla1", "blabla2")) 
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
    docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)

cor<-Corpus(VectorSource(texts$Reviews))
    dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
    m <- as.matrix(dtm)
    v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
    d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
    head(d, 20)
    findFreqTerms(dtm, 10)
```

Comment: Couldn't you just filter out the words you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the frequency of specific words, you can use the dictionary option in the control part of `DocumentTermMatrix`.

in your case:

```
my_words <- c("love", "like" , "best")
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(dictionary = my_words))
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tm)

data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

my_words <- c("oil", "contract")

my_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control = list(dictionary = my_words))

inspect(my_dtm)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 20, terms: 2)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 24/16
Sparsity           : 40%
Maximal term length: 8
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
     Terms
Docs  contract oil
  127        2   5
  144        0  12
  236        0   7
  246        0   5
  248        0   9
  273        0   5
  349        0   4
  352        0   5
  353        0   4
  502        0   5
```

Comment: Thank you i got the output :-)